# ¿Porque al cambiar un valor de una lista Auxiliar cambia la lista original?

Tags: vb.net

Tengo definida una lista como: `FileForces` y otra como `AuxFilesForces`, añado los valores de `FileForces` en `AuxFilesForces` a través de un ciclo, como se puede ver al inicio de la rutina `Calcular()`, luego modifico algunos valores de la lista `AuxFilesForces` como se muestra en las filas del `If V2 > 0 Then`, al depurar el código, observo que las dos Listas se modifican, como puedo hacer para que solo se modifique `AuxFilesForces` y no `FileForces` y ¿porque ocurre esto?

```
Module Module1
Public FileForces As New List(Of List(Of String))
Public FilesForcesAuxiliar As New List(Of List(Of String))

Sub Calcular()
 For i = 0 To FileForces.Count - 1
    FilesForcesAuxiliar.Add(FileForces(i))
 Next


  For i = 0 To FilesForcesAuxiliar.Count - 1

            Dim NameBeam As String = FilesForcesAuxiliar(i)(1)
            Dim StoryName As String = FilesForcesAuxiliar(i)(0)
            Dim V2 As Double = Val(FilesForcesAuxiliar(i)(5))

            For j = 0 To List_LieneAssigns.Count - 1

                If NameBeam = List_LieneAssigns(j).Name And StoryName = List_LieneAssigns(j).StoryName Then

                    Dim d = List_LieneAssigns(j).Section.H - List_LieneAssigns(j).Section.R
                    Dim fi_vc = 0.75 * 0.53 * Math.Sqrt((List_LieneAssigns(j).Section.Material.FC) / 10) * List_LieneAssigns(j).Section.B * d

                    If V2 > 0 Then
                        FilesForcesAuxiliar(i)(5) = Str(V2 + fi_vc)
                    Else
                        FilesForcesAuxiliar(i)(5) = Str(V2 - fi_vc)
                    End If
                End If

            Next

Next
End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las listas son objetos que se manejan por referencia, de modo que cuando asignas una lista no estás asignando una copia sino una referencia a la lista original. Para resolver esto. deberías "copiar" efectivamente la lista, por ejemplo:

En vez de crear `FilesForcesAuxiliar` de esta forma:

```
For i = 0 To FileForces.Count - 1
    FilesForcesAuxiliar.Add(FileForces(i))
Next
```

Podrías hacerlo así:

```
For Each l As List(Of String) In FileForces
    FilesForcesAuxiliar.add(l.ToList())
Next l
```

`ToList()` crea una nueva lista por cada elemento de `FileForces` por el cual estás iterando